# Extracting a 2000 pages table from a website to Excel

Tags: excel, web-scraping

I have that webpage which I can search for HS codes and it reveals the exact name and custom`s procedure, I want to extract this full table almost 2300 Pages or make Excel sheet connected to this website to enable me search via Excel. I hope this is possible to be done.
The website is http://www.customs.gov.sa/sites/sc/en/SCTariffs/Pages/Pages/SearchTariffsPage%20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the network tab in the developer tools in Firefox to determine the urls of the webservice/pages that return the actual data.

Then you can use vba to generate your own set of urls and download the entire data set.

You could also use Selenium to automate your browser to achieve the same thing.

Of course, you might just consider asking the government for the information in the format you require.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i could not apply any of the first two options which seems to need programmer in the first place, for third option i already tried to contact the website admin to provide excel file for that table with no feedback and still trying to.

Comment: At least you know where you stand :0). There is a way to import data directly from a website into Excel (though i suspect it's not smart enough to do what you want anyway!), but even that would require some degree of programming ability. You might find someone to implement one of the solutions on odesk.com, if you don't hear back from the website admin. You should hear back though, because it is in the governments interest to provide people with correct, accessible information!